# Specifying a deadline in .NET code-first gRPC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

Using .NET's code-first gRPC, how are deadlines specified when services are invoked? Microsoft's [Reliable gRPC services with deadlines and cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/deadlines-cancellation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) page only has examples for non code-first invocation.

My gRPC interface is passed a `CallContext`, as specified by [Code-first gRPC services and clients with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-5.0), however there are no examples on that page - or, on any other pages I could find - on how this is expected to be used.

Looking at `CallContext`'s code, it can be passed a `ServerCallContext` which contains a deadline. However, this class is abstract and the only implementations I can find are internal.

Finally, there is `CallContext.Default` which contains a `Deadline`, however this class is immutable so is again of little help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as soon as I posted that, I found the approach:

```cs
var deadline = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(15);
var context = CallContext.Default.CallOptions.WithDeadline(deadline);

await myService.DoStuffAsync(context);
```